# Committed my changes instead of git merge --continue

Tags: git, git-merge

I was trying to rebase my branch through `git merge master`. Upon running the command I discovered that I am having conflicts, so I resolved them and accidently committed the changes through VScode GUI (Instead of `git merge --continue`). Upon returning to git bash (CLI), I ran `git merge --continue` and it throws an error saying *There is no merge in progress. (MERGE_HEAD missing)*.

What should I do?

Comment: "What should I do?" Nothing. Get on with life! You did fine.

Comment: Committing things on your own instead of `git  merge --continue` is the same thing? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: Since you had done the merge at the GUI, so I think there's no point to do it at CLI again, as there is nothing need to merge anymore

Comment: Yes, exactly. Added it as an answer.

Comment: For `git merge`, it's both okay to use `git commit` or `git merge --continue` to end the conflicts. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_to_resolve_conflicts. For `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick`, it's a bit different when applying multiple commits. `git commit` ends the rebase or cherry-pick process and leaves the rest commits undone. Maybe my memory goes wrong. Maybe git has improved it. I tried the latest git and find that `git commit` now does not completely end the process.

Answer (score 0):

A merge is a commit. Performing a merge with no conflict makes that commit. Continuing a merge after pausing because of a conflict also just makes that commit! Well, that's what *you* did, and you had fixed the conflict, so if that file is fine now, there is no more to do. The merge is over.  Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: Alright. Thanks! Seems like I was getting worried for nothing haha.

Comment: @AashishAggarwal https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers